# How can we access provider without ref object in flutter_riverpod?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, riverpod

Suppose you are trying to manipulate a provider at some place where you don't have access to a WidgetRef object.

Usually we access a provider like this,
`final yourProvider = ref.read('your_provider');`

Can we manipulate the provider state without the ref object here.

As in Getx we, being at any place can access the controller with,

```
YourGetXController controller = Get.find();
controller.value = newValue;
```

Tried few solutions from internet and chatGPT but not being able to figure out how. Tring if it can be done with flutter_riverpod, because the app is built with flutter_riverpod. I need the above mentioned scenario to work at one particular place. If I don't find a solution I'll use GetX for this particular scenario.

Comment: Where in your project are you that you don't have a ref object? If it is in some random function or class method, you can usually just pass the Ref object as an argument from whichever widget/provider/notifier you're calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetX - it's a variation on the architecture of how not to do it. In this case, there is no way you can externally access the provider state without using `ref`. All you can do is:

1. Pass `Ref` as an argument to a function where inside will require access to the provider. (bad pattern)
2. Use `ProviderScope.containerOf(context)` to get a reference to the current `ProviderContainer` where it is possible to `read` the provider value
3. Use a class the `Notifier` class, where `ref` is available as a getter inside the class.

In any case, if you have access to data as global variables, it will soon turn into a terrible mess of untraceable code.

Comment: Is there any way a Riverpod notification can be triggered from a non-widget class? For example, a background service object like an MQTT client, which is not associated with a UI context.